# Top Navigation Bar in a game Not Working Properly only in Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, uinavigationcontroller, uniwebview

In our Game which we developed using Unity, we recently updated the IAP plugin to upgrade the Google Play Billing to v4. Now we have an android specific problem in our builds. In our android builds, the navigation bar becomes unusable when we start the mini slot games which we have used in our main game using WebView.

In the iOS builds, the navigation bar works perfectly. The problem is only in the android builds.

Would really appreciate if someone could help.

Thank you!

The uniWebView version used is most probably 3.18.1.

I tried changing Z-Index, embedding and iFrame of the navigation bar. I also tried tweaking with the uniwebview but ended up messing even more.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the UniWebView to version 5 worked like a charm. :)